# allowing timeouts for commands that have no timeout option, where `IFS=$'\n'`

Tags: macos, script, shell-script

In the lines below, which I added to my copy of Apple's `sysdiagnose` script:

- wherever a timeout is already scripted, it is effective
- I must **add timeouts in two areas, but I don't know how to do so**.

In the two areas, `IFS=$'\n'` …

```
# If there exists a zfs binary, get some ZFS information
if [ -f "${ZFS}" ]
then
    #
    # The pool part
    #
    "${ECHO}" "Recording ZFS pool version information ..."
    "${ZPOOL}" upgrade &> ${data_directory_path}/"ZFS pools and properties.txt" &
    add_timeout_pid $! 30
    "${ECHO}" "    listing all ZFS pools ..."
    "${ECHO}" "" >> ${data_directory_path}/"ZFS pools and properties.txt"
    "${ECHO}" "ZFS pools:" >> ${data_directory_path}/"ZFS pools and properties.txt"
    "${ECHO}" "" >> ${data_directory_path}/"ZFS pools and properties.txt"
    "${ZPOOL}" list >> ${data_directory_path}/"ZFS pools and properties.txt" &
    add_timeout_pid $! 30
    "${ECHO}" "    all properties of each pool ..."
    OLD_IFS=$IFS
    IFS=$'\n'
    # If cut or zpool can not progress, then at this point: sysdiagnose will not progress  
    # <https://superuser.com/q/540939/84988>
    for zfspool in `"${ZPOOL}" list -H | cut -f 1`
    do
        { echo "\n*********************\n" ; "${ZPOOL}" get all "$zfspool" ; } >> ${data_directory_path}/"ZFS pools and properties.txt"
    done
    IFS=$OLD_IFS
    "${ECHO}" "    detailed health status and verbose data error information ..."
    "${ZPOOL}" status -v &> ${data_directory_path}/"ZFS pool detailed health status and verbose data error information.txt" &
    add_timeout_pid $! 30
    "${ECHO}" "    pools that are available but not currently imported"
    "${ZPOOL}" import &> ${data_directory_path}/"ZFS pools not imported.txt" &
    add_timeout_pid $! 30
    #
    # The file system part
    #
    "${ECHO}" "Recording ZFS file system version information ..."
    { "${ZFS}" upgrade ; "${ECHO}" "\n" ; } &> ${data_directory_path}/"ZFS file systems and properties.txt" &
    add_timeout_pid $! 30
    "${ECHO}" "    listing all ZFS file systems ..."
    #"${ECHO}" "ZFS file systems:" >> ${data_directory_path}/"ZFS file systems and properties.txt"
    "${ZFS}" list >> ${data_directory_path}/"ZFS file systems and properties.txt" &
    add_timeout_pid $! 30
    "${ECHO}" "    all properties of each file system"
    OLD_IFS=$IFS
    IFS=$'\n'
    # If cut or zfs can not progress, then at this point: sysdiagnose will not progress  
    # <https://superuser.com/q/540939/84988>
    for zfsfilesystem in `zfs list -H | cut -f 1`
    do
        { echo "\n*********************\n" ; "${ZFS}" get all "$zfsfilesystem" ; } >> ${data_directory_path}/"ZFS file systems and properties.txt"
    done
    IFS=$OLD_IFS
    #
    # Directory listings
    #
    "${ECHO}" "Listing the contents of /dev/dsk"
    { "${ECHO}" "Directory listing for /dev/dsk" ; echo "\n"; } >> ${data_directory_path}/"ZEVO-oriented directory listings.txt"
    { "${LS}" -@ael /dev/dsk ; echo "\n*********************\n" ; } >> ${data_directory_path}/"ZEVO-oriented directory listings.txt" &
    add_timeout_pid $! 30
    "${ECHO}" "Listing the contents of /var/zfs/dsk"
    { "${ECHO}" "Directory listing for /var/zfs/dsk" ; echo "\n" ; } >> ${data_directory_path}/"ZEVO-oriented directory listings.txt"
    "${LS}" -@ael /var/zfs/dsk >> ${data_directory_path}/"ZEVO-oriented directory listings.txt" &
    add_timeout_pid $! 30
fi
```

Note the comment:

`# If cut or zpool can not progress, then at this point: sysdiagnose will not progress`

## Question

How can I write `add_timeout_pid $! 30` into those two areas?

### Background

Whilst I can't reproduce the script in its entirety (it's not open source), users of Lion and greater may find Apple's script human-readable:

`/usr/bin/sysdiagnose`

#### Links

[sysdiagnose(1) OS X Manual Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sysdiagnose.1.html)

[cut(1) OS X Manual Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cut.1.html)

The [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/535913/84988) to [Handling whitespaces in the name of a ZFS dataset in a shell script](https://superuser.com/q/528942/84988)

Also in Super User, [Force a bash script to run to completion where some items may stick](https://superuser.com/q/210248/84988)
– but the answer there is no good for commands (such as `cut`, `zfs` and `zpool`) that have **no timeout option**.

Comment: The timeout features requires you to run things in a subshell in the background, see the other uses of that function in the existing script. The results are then only collected after `timeout` is called, all data gathering processes redirect their output somewhere. Just wrap *all* your ZFS diagnosis in a subshell, and timeout that process, similar to "`Gather simple diskutil list`".

Comment: @DanielBeck I'm looking now but can't see what you mean – sorry. I'm easily confused with scripts, and generally a bit dyslexic about learning things … I need some hand-holding here to avoid learning the wrong lessons …

Comment: All occurrences of `add_timeout_pid` in the original script immediately follow commands *executed in the background* using the `&` at the end (e.g. line 544-545, 688-689). Only in line 768 will the entire script wait for all of these to complete. Your use case, with multiple commands etc. is covered by what happens in a sub-shell (see the bash docs on "Compound Commands") with `diskutil` in lines 502-512. Try to understand how this works, and follow those rules with your new sub-script (e.g. not running the timeout function after every command). Line numbers from 10.8.2 used.